# How to display the amount of documents in a collection in ejs? With mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, ejs

I am trying to display the amount of available documents that are in a collection. The collection name is "merchant1".

This is the backend:

```js
router.get('/merchanttrading', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
const user = req.user;
merchant1.find({},  function (error, data) { 
res.render("merchanttrading", {data, user: req.user});
})
})
```

And this is what I am trying in the front end:

```html
<% for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { %>
<h2 id="test"><%= data[i].length%></h2>
<% } %>




<script>

<% for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { %>
var documentamount = <%= data[i]%>
<% } %>


</script>
```

But this will just up ending beign blank. Rendering the entire document just works fine but what I want is to show the amount of current documents in the collection as a number and not the document itself.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution after more digging I came across this: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/

Then I used that like this:

```js
router.get('/merchanttrading', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
const user = req.user;
merchant1.count({},  function (error, data) { 
res.render("merchanttrading", {data, user: req.user});
})
})
```

The solution seemed to easier then I thought and I was just over thinking it.